# Split data in a Python List

Tags: python, list, split

`['3:20 pm–4:30 pm', '3:20 pm–4:30 pm', '7:05 am–8:00 am', '11:20 am–12:20 pm', '5:25 pm–6:25 pm', '1:55 pm–5:40 pm', '7:00 am–11:05 am', '3:30 pm–7:00 pm', '6:10 pm–9:55 pm', '6:20 pm–9:15 pm', '6:30 am–11:30 am', '7:00 am–10:55 am', '7:30 am–10:35 am', '6:30 am–9:55 am', '5:50 pm–9:15 pm', '7:25 am–11:05 am', '10:40 am–3:40 pm', '11:45 am–3:15 pm', '7:00 am–12:00 pm', '7:00 am–11:55 am', '7:40 am–12:00 pm', '5:20 am–9:55 am', '11:15 am–3:30 pm', '7:40 am–11:05 am', '12:45 pm–6:10 pm', '10:05 am–3:15 pm', '3:30 pm–9:05 pm', '7:15 am–12:00 pm', '7:00 am–12:55 pm', '7:35 am–12:00 pm', '7:25 am–12:00 pm']`

I scrapped this list form the kayak using selenium, now i want to separate these two time slots
ex: `'3.20 pm', '4.30 pm'`, how can i do that in python?

I need to arrange this two separate lists, one is `arrival_time` and other is `departure_time`

so far I used this

```
split_list = []
split_list = [e.split('\u2013') for e in lst_time] 
print(split_list)
```

Comment: Take a look at str.split(). Note that the separator is an en-dash (\u2013) and not, as you might have thought, a hyphen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Are you aware of `str.split()`? Do you know how to [do the same thing to each element in a list](/q/25082410/4518341)? Do you know how to [split apart a list of tuples](/q/19339/4518341)? Or, another possibility is using Pandas, which takes care of the legwork for you: `.str.split('\u2013', expand=True).set_axis(['arrival_time', 'departure_time'], axis='columns')`

Answer (score 1):

You cansplit the items using the string split method since they are strings such as

```
split_list = []

for item in item_list:
    start,end = item.split('-')
    split_list.append([start, end])
```

Comment: Or *split_list = [e.split('\u2013') for e in item_list]* to get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Of course .split() is the way, but i noteice that your expected output wants . insted : ad hours-minutes separator.

So thats 's my solution:

```
data = ['3:20 pm–4:30 pm', '3:20 pm–4:30 pm', '7:05 am–8:00 am', '11:20 am–12:20 pm']

output = []

for time_range_str in data:
   start_time, end_time = time_range_str.split('–')
   start_time = start_time.strip().replace(":", ".")
   end_time = end_time.strip().replace(":", ".")
   output.extend([start_time, end_time])

print(output)
```